# Velocity.js SVG Text Position Animation

Tags: javascript, svg, attributes, velocity.js

I am trying to get Velocity.js to animate the position of an SVG text element like this:

```
Velocity(svg.getElementById('projects-title'), {
    x: '50%',
    y: '25%'
  });
```

The issue is that it changes these values in the style attribute, not the attributes themselves. Therefore, not changing the position of the element. The resulting element is this:

```
<text x="50%" y="50%" id="projects-title" class="" style="x: 50%; y: 25%;">Projects</text>
```

How can I make Velocity.js change the attributes instead of the element's CSS styling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this may be helpful, You could easily control any kind of attributes using TweenMax lib.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var tl = new TimelineMax();
    tl.set("#projects-title", {
        x: '50%',
        y: '25%'
    });

</script>
```